# Xamarin iOS Webkit: How do I resolve NIDActionArity1V59?

Tags: ios, xamarin, webkit

I need to override the following `DecidePolicy()` in a subclass but I get build errors because the compiler isn't able to resolve `NIDActionArity1V59`. Where is `NIDActionArity1V59` implemented so I can apply the required `using` statement,

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Foundation;
using ObjCRuntime;

namespace WebKit
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Delegate object for WebKit.WKNavigation objects, provides methods relating to
    //     navigation and load policies.
    [Introduced(PlatformName.MacOSX, 10, 10, PlatformArchitecture.Arch64, null)]
    [Introduced(PlatformName.iOS, 8, 0, PlatformArchitecture.None, null)]
    [Model]
    [Protocol]
    [Register("WKNavigationDelegate", false)]
    public class WKNavigationDelegate : NSObject, IWKNavigationDelegate, INativeObject, IDisposable
    {
        [...]
        //
        // Summary:
        //     Assigns an action to be taken after the specified navigationAction has been either
        //     canceled or allowed.
        [CompilerGenerated]
        [Export("webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:")]
        public virtual void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, [BlockProxy(typeof(NIDActionArity1V59))] Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy> decisionHandler);


        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to find this within the `Trampolines.cs` class if you're decompiling. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/runtime/docs/trampolines/ However you should probably just have a definition like:

```public override void DecidePolicy (WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy> decisionHandler)```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need this attribute? You can simply override it like

```
public class MyNavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{
    public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy> decisionHandler)
    {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

The `BlockProxy` attribute is only used internally as far as I know. https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/ObjCRuntime.BlockProxyAttribute/

And if you have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/WebKit.WKNavigationDelegate/) you will not see a single attribute, because they aren't part of the signature of a function. So I guess, you confused yourself a bit by looking too deep in the decompiled sources ;)

**Tip:**
When you type `override` followed by a space, Visual Studio offers you the correct overloads. So you have not to search for them.

[image]